# Is there an equivalent for PHP PDO in Python?

Tags: php, python, pdo

My favorite element of PHP is the PDO object. Is there a library or built in module for Python that can rival it?

Comment: Python dbo http://sourceforge.net/projects/pythondbo/ is called PDO too

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you taken a look at [Python Database Objects](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Python-Database-Objects-PDO/1.3.1) ?

Comment: "Last released: Jul 28, 2004" :(

Comment: Careful with this library. It's too outdated.

Comment: @KoushikDas so what will be the alternative?

Comment: I don't know any alternative which is maintained well @mondayrris

Answer (score 0):

pyodbc is probably the closest to it.

https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc

> pyodbc is an open source Python module that makes accessing ODBC databases simple. It implements the DB API 2.0 specification but is packed with even more Pythonic convenience.

I have not tried it myself yet but thought I would share after also bumping into this question.